# ClassNotFoundException DexPathList adMob

Tags: android, admob, classnotfoundexception

i have my project called "fantacalcio2" and i would like to add an admob banner.
Application works fine, but when i add xml banner i have this exception and app just crash at start. How can i fix that? This is my log:

```
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565): Process: com.falc1.fantacalcio2, PID: 19565
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.falc1.fantacalcio2/com.falc1.fantacalcio2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:707)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at com.falc1.fantacalcio2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    ... 11 more
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.ads.AdView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.falc1.fantacalcio2-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.falc1.fantacalcio2-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:559)
    09-13 18:54:49.813: E/AndroidRuntime(19565):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
```

And this is xml layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >     


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="adunit"
        android:gravity="bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Nobody knows how to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have not included the Admob classes in your APK.

Note also that you are attempting to use the old Admob classes (6.4.1 and before). You should really be using the new classes from Google Play Services.

See https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/banner